# Add live video parts to MSE buffer

Tags: javascript, html5-video, media-source

I'm trying to play a live video stream using html5 video and Media Source Extension. From a live streaming device I receive videos in the mp4 format, each 2 seconds long, over sockets.io.

How can I add these 2-seconds-mp4-videos to the MSE buffer? I saw some examples streaming a (not live) video with fixed length. But in my case it's different because it doesn't have a fixed length nor a known number of parts it is/can be split in. Some working code highly appreciated!

Additionally the live video should start to play as soon as the first 2-seconds-video is downloaded (while future 2-seconds-videos are downloaded and added to the buffer as they are available).

Comment: Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nthyfgvs/ It may be what you're looking for.